# IIS Production Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, iis-8, webdeploy

I am having trouble figuring out the methods on publishing publicly on IIS 8.  I have a test application running on my localhost but what are the next steps to publish it for anyone to get to?

Comment: You simply want to publish to a server fully under your controll?

Comment: @harmoniemand yes I would like to pubish to a server under my control but instead of my localhost. A server that will allow the application to be displayed by anyone

Answer (score 0):

For publishing i recommended WebDeploy

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later

Its a simple way to deploy with only one click from visual studio.